# Cross-cutting delete flag in a repository

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I want to have a cross-cutting delete flag in my repository. I have the following repository pattern at the moment:

```
public interface IRepo<TModel> where TModel : EntityBase<int>
    {
        TModel Add(TModel item);
        void Add(IEnumerable<TModel> entities);
        TModel Remove(TModel item);
        TModel Find(int itemId);
        TModel Get(int itemId);
        IQueryable<TModel> Query { get; }
    }
```

I am exposing `IQueryable` which makes it hard to control whether deleted entities are retrieved or not in my service layer. Would adding a method to my repository which replaces Query and exposes a pre-filtered `IEnumerable` be bad form?

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll
{
    get { return this.dbset.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false); }
}
```

I am assuming since `IQueryable` is lazily loaded I won't pulling more entities into memory than required? Is this naive?

Comment: You don't need `AsEnumerable()`. Return `IQueryable<TEntity>` and just do `return dbSet.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted);`. You've stumbled across one of the many reasons I dislike having a "standard" repository interface though.

Comment: @RobH - thanks for the comment. Do you want to leave this as an answer? I feel it satisfies the question.

Comment: slightly expanded on my comment in an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `AsEnumerable` on the `DbSet` in fact, doing so isn't great at all... As far as I am aware, this will make your `Where` clause execute in C# rather than being translated to SQL meaning a massive perf hit (I would be happy to be corrected here).

You should return `IQueryable<TEntity>` directly:

```
return dbSet.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted);
```

Notice that I've removed the redundant `this.` and also changed the comparison to use `!` (not operator) instead of comparing to `false`.

One additional warning I would give you is: are you **sure** you need a generic base class repository? I find that when I have used this pattern a lot of my repositories get methods they never use.

It can also be argued that it's a leaky abstraction, see e.g [here](http://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern/) and [here](http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/)

I prefer slim interfaces of only a few methods rather than using [header interfaces](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/HeaderInterface.html).